# Problem initializing Firebase on Flutter Legacy App (Android only)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, crashlytics

I'm working on a Flutter legacy app (pre null safety, channel stable v1.22.5), I want to use Firebase for Analytics and Crashlytics only and, for the time being, the app cannot be updated to null-safety (some custom dependencies are still outdated)

When initializing, I get this error `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)` at `await Firebase.initializeApp();`.

### Here is some info about files / code:

### main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
//other imports...


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); <- Here the app crashes

  runApp(App());
}
```

### pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"
  //other dependencies...

  firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_crashlytics: "^0.4.0+1"
  firebase_analytics: "^7.0.0"
```

I have followed throughly the SDK installation instructions and this is what I have added in `build.gradle` and app-level `build.gradle`:

### build.gradle (/android)

```
   buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5' <- New
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.1' <- New
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### app-level build.gradle (android/app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.my_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' <- New 
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2') <- New
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' <- New
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics' <- New
}
```

#### flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1237], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at C:\Users\jorge.rincon\Documents\flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (10 months ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\jorge.rincon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.60.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.27.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)
```

### Other info

My app `package_name` is the same for `google-services.json`, `build.gradle` and all the `AndroidManifest.xml` and it goes like `com.example.my_app`

I have tried running `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` but no luck, also wiping all the android simulator data, tried different emulators...

Also, both Crashlytics and Analytics are enabled in the Firebase Console.

Any insight is really appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you done this part: `// TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID `

Comment: Since I had the same issue with old codebases, updating it will be your best bet.

Comment: Hello! Yes, that’s just an old comment but it has an unique name. Updating is not an option right now I’m afraid :(